# addAll to Set is not adding the values in java

Tags: java, collections, set, addition

I have a property in an Object(Obj1)

```
Set<AssignedService> serviceList;
public Set<AssignedService> getServiceList();
```

I am doing the below operation in certain instances

```
Obj1.getServiceList().clear();
Obj1.getServiceList().addAll(services);
```

where Services is also Set

But what I see as an end result is services set is having 4 objects/data elements
but Obj1.getServiceList() is returning an empty set after addAll

What's the issue here. is it a problem with AssignedService object since it doesn't implements IComparable

Comment: Yes it would be good the implement `Comparable<AssignedService>` (and nice to have correct methods for equals and hashCode). You can check services.size(). Should be 0. Otherwise I would have expected at least one element. Maybe you ignore Exceptions somewhere in an empty catch. You did not initialize with Collections.emptySet() which is read-only?

Comment: Collections.emptySet() what's that

Comment: There is `Collections.emptySet()` (and List, ...) to create a type-safe unmodifiable Set of zero elements. Likewise there are `Collections.singleton...` functions for one element.

Comment: (1) What is the implementing class of `serviceList`? (2) What is in `services`? Debugging should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first read this [excellent piece](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) on `.equals()`

Then, as others have pointed out, check your implementation of `equals()` **and** `.hashcode()` on the `AssignedService` class. Most likely the root cause is found here.

You could also check the return value of the `.addAll(...)` call - `false` would indicate that the underlying `Set` isn't modified by the method call.

Cheers,

Comment: I am guessing the issue can be the same one. But my Class is an Entity class of Hibernate. I am worried if I write these extra methods, it may impact overall applications as we are at the end of delivery. Is there any way to implement for this specific case by writing Anonymous Inner classes. Using JDK 1.6

Comment: There is no problem in overriding `equals(...)` and `hashCode()` in `@Entity` classes.

Comment: in hashCode, can I just call return super.hashCode() in hashCode() method or do I need to write something.

Comment: Quick answer: No! Longer answer: That depends on your notion of equality for the concrete class. In very broad terms you should generate the hashcode based on the same attributes for which you define `equals()` - do read the link I mention, it explains everything very neatly!

Answer (score 0):

Check the implementation of equals() in AssignedService.

[Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html): A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

Comment: missing `equals()` doesn't explain an empty result set.

Comment: If equals always returns true, no element will be added to the set - apart from the first one maybe.

Comment: Obviously there can be hundred of bugs leading to this behaviour, including getServiceList() returning a new empty set at every request.